# Darkening effect is superimposed on the splash screen

Tags: android, flutter, manifest, splash-screen

I implemented splash screen using `flutter_native_splash`, everything is fine in the emulator, both in dark mode and light mode, but as soon as I install it on my physical phone (poco android 12), in dark mode, a  darkening effect is superimposed on the splash screen. Maybe someone has encountered and knows how to fix it.

My code

```yaml
flutter_native_splash:

  color: "#FFB223"
  color_dark: "#FFB223"
  image: assets/images/logo_for_splash.png
  image_dark: assets/images/logo_for_splash.png
  android: true
  ios: false
  web: false

  android_12:
    color: "#FFB223"
    color_dark: "#FFB223"
    image: assets/images/logo_for_splash.png
    image_dark: assets/images/logo_for_splash.png
```

Manifest

```xml
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:exported="true"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    <!-- I can try delete this. -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
        android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
        />
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

App in dark and light mode on my physical phone.
[image]